# disable button based on the condition

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a table where when clicking a button, I need to disable the button if the status from the backend is approved. I added the disable property to the button based on the condition but the condition is not working.

If I use the condition `.receiptStatus=='APPROVED'` it's not working.

```js
this.receipt = this.dataSource.data;
this.receipts = this.receipt.forEach(element => {
  this.receivableStatus = element.status
  console.log(this.receivableStatus);
});
// this.receivableStatus has the response from the backend.
```

```css
.disable {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button mat-raised-button mat-button-sm class="table-action-btn" color="orange" 
[disabled]="this.receiptStatus=='APPROVED'" 
[ngClass]="{'disable':this.receiptStatus=='APPROVED'}" (click)="openCreateReceipt(row)">
  <mat-icon class="size-16" color="white">edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Does the network tab show the expected status?

Comment: yes ,but i used another way to disable it , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not use `this` in HTML.

```
<button mat-raised-button mat-button-sm class="table-action-btn" color="orange" 
[disabled]="receiptStatus=='APPROVED'" 
[ngClass]="{receiptStatus=='APPROVED' ? 'disable' : ''}" (click)="openCreateReceipt(row)">
  <mat-icon class="size-16" color="white">edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @morphen yes , but if i didnt use this also it is not working i dont know whats the problem.but i used another way to get it done, but still iam confused what is the issue with this logic

Comment: THIS keyword @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution for this , i have done it on another way .since iam using matatable datasource to display the status in the status column i used that

```
 <button mat-raised-button mat-button-sm class="table-action-btn" 
color="orange"[disabled]="row.status=='APPROVED'"
[ngClass]="{'disable':row.status=='APPROVED'}"
(click)="openCreateReceipt(row)">
  <mat-icon class="size-16" color="white">edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

it works fine.